# how to grep boldface text

Tags: bash, grep

There is a text which contains boldface words, for example, like man pages. How to grep only that bold text? A boldface text can contain "-". For example,

```
echo -e "Normal \e[1mBold1 \e[21mNormal Normal \e[1m--Bold-2 \e[21mNormal"
```

returns

```
Normal **Bold1** Normal Normal **--Bold-2** Normal
```

Now I want something like

```
echo -e "Normal \e[1mBold1 \e[21mNormal Normal \e[1mBold-2 \e[21mNormal" | egrep -o 'bold only'
```

So the output is:

**Bold1**
  **--Bold-2**

I tried something like

```
echo -e "Normal \e[1mBold1 \e[21mNormal Normal \e[1m--Bold-2 \e[21mNormal" | egrep "\e\[1mBold1 \e\[21m"
```

but it returns nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that in the output you aren't getting `\e` or anything like that. You are getting an escape character. (Dump the output into `xxd` to see what I mean.

Which means you need to have a literal escape character in your grep pattern.

The simplest way to do that is probably to use `$'..'` quoting.

```
echo -e "Normal \e[1mBold1 \e[0mNormal Normal \e[1m--Bold-2 \e[0mNormal" | grep -P -o $'\e\[1m.*?\e\[0m'
```

That being said this is a very ugly thing to be doing in general and would absolutely be best avoided.

Comment: On macOS, one can run the above command by using echo and grep from GNU : `brew install coreutils grep` then prefixing the echo and grep commands with a `g` to run their GNU siblings: `gecho -e "Normal \e[1mBold1 \e[0mNormal Normal \e[1m--Bold-2 \e[0mNormal" | ggrep -P -o $'\e\[1m.*?\e\[0m'`

Comment: and use `bash` apparently